# How to fetch an int value using PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have a postgred db, and I want to fetch a specific int value from a table, and then add it to an existing value. This is my code:

```
global $conn;

$qnt_actual = $conn->prepare('select qnt_armazem from stock2  where brinquedo= :brinquedo'); 
$qnt_actual->bindParam(':brinquedo', $brinquedo);
$qnt_actual->execute();
$qnt_actual->fetch();
$qnt_actual2=$qnt_actual->fetch();

$quantidade=$quantidade+$qnt_actual2;
```

But when I echo $quantidade, it assumes $qnt_actual2=0. Also, when I echo $qnt_actual2, it doesn't echo anything, not even 0.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you call `fetch` twice?

Comment: @MarcelGwerder  that was exactly what was wrong with the code!! It works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

Everytime you call `fetch()`,  `PDO` fetches the next row from the result set.

Since you have only one row, calling `fetch()` twice would not find a row the second time you call it.

**Solution:**

Call `fetch()` only once.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong code, duplicate call object. this one object fetch().

```
$qnt_actual->fetch();  <------- Remove
$qnt_actual2=$qnt_actual->fetch();
```

Right

```
$qnt_actual2 = $qnt_actual->fetch();

print_r($qnt_actual2);  <------ return results view.
```

Sory, my English not good.